# Использование cookies через htmlunit

Tags: java, cookie, htmlunit

Как в `htmlunit` использовать куки на одном и том же сайте. Логинюсь к сайту, вывожу результат как текст. Написано что "вход произведен успешно". Перехожу на главную страницу этого сайта и там написано что не залогинился (Войти, зарегестрироваться написано).
Создаю `WebClient` так:

```
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
        CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
        webClient.setCookieManager(cm);
```

Пишет:

```
WARNING: Cookie rejected [phpbb3_la4i4_u="6020", version:0, domain:unity3d.ru, path:/, expiry:Fri Aug 11 02:26:54 VLAT 2017] Illegal 'domain' attribute "unity3d.ru". Domain of origin: "sync.audtd.com"
авг 11, 2016 2:26:52 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Cookie rejected [phpbb3_la4i4_k="", version:0, domain:unity3d.ru, path:/, expiry:Fri Aug 11 02:26:54 VLAT 2017] Illegal 'domain' attribute "unity3d.ru". Domain of origin: "sync.audtd.com"
авг 11, 2016 2:26:52 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Cookie rejected [phpbb3_la4i4_sid="40411e762a59c3ce238e765b05a5af58", version:0, domain:unity3d.ru, path:/, expiry:Fri Aug 11 02:26:54 VLAT 2017] Illegal 'domain' attribute "unity3d.ru". Domain of origin: "sync.audtd.com"
авг 11, 2016 2:26:53 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
```

И таких надписей куча

Answer (score 1):

Перед кликом на кнопку авторизации отключил `JavaScript`

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Заработало